# CSP: "script-src" difference between Firefox 83 and Chromium 87?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chromium, content-security-policy

We've got a Web site with the following CSP:

```
Content-Security-Policy: base-uri 'self';default-src 'self';font-src 'self' data:;frame-src 'self' *.project-open.net;img-src 'self';object-src 'none';report-uri /SYSTEM/csp-collector.tcl;script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-071AAEB62D9B05B24B13B76A3AECA620EBFF732B';style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
```

We've got a search-box with some minor JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="071AAEB62D9B05B24B13B76A3AECA620EBFF732B ">
alert('xxx');
</script>
```

Everything works fine in Chromium, but FireFox shows an error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

Google's [CSP checker](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) returned all green.
Any idea about the source of this incompatibility or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old [Firefox bug](https://csplite.com/csp/test341/) with wrong attributes parsing - it does not remove trailing spaces.
Just remove trailing space in `nonce="071AAEB62D9B05B24B13B76A3AECA620EBFF732B ">` value.